# How to show/hide electron titlebar (close, maximise and minimize)

Tags: angular, electron, html5-video

I have an electron app and there is an option to play video content. The video player itself has a close button, so in full screen mode I want the player window to be shown on top, which means the user should first close the video player and only then can access the electron controls. Is it possible? If so, what are the ways to do it?